# how spark speculation mechanism kills a task

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

some NodeManagers may be manually killed so corresponding executors will lost, thus failed task that had ran on such node will accumulated to the max retries.
So I want to imitate spark's speculation killing the task because its  "another attempt succeeded" doesn't count to max failures. we just want the application to continues to run if we killed a nm manually.